# SQL como fazer para que me retorne o número de intervalos negativos (INTERVAL de date)

Tags: sql

dif_dataativacao_fimdegus é um intervalo da diferença entre 2 campos de data, que me voltar, por exemplo, -1 day.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer um count de todos os registros que são negativos nessa coluna.

Comment: Qual SGBD esta utilizando?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor a sua primeira linha? dif_dataativacao_fimdegus seria uma function que te retorna a diferença entre datas?

Answer (score 0):

Faltam dados mas será algo assim

testando apenas valores negativos

```
select count(dif_dataativacao_fimdegus) soma
from tabela
where dif_dataativacao_fimdegus <= -1
```

ou

tratando uma coluna com apenas valores negativos

```
select count(case when dif_dataativacao_fimdegus <= -1 then
                dif_dataativacao_fimdegus else null end) soma_do_neg,
      count(dif_dataativacao_fimdegus) soma
from tabela
```

Pós observação do @ramaral, creio ser isto , mas repito ficou pouco clara 9ao menos para mim) a dúvida.

Comment: Reveja a sua resposta pois o que o AP quer é ***"um count de todos os registros que são negativos nessa coluna"***